# p:fileDownload not working from modal dialog (due to ajax="false")

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, download, dialog

I need to use PrimeFaces `p:fileDownload` from within a data-table inside a modal dialog, but due to the use of ajax="false" (else the file download won't be triggered) inside command button the dialog disappears. Do you have any clue?

```
<p:commandLink value="#{row.name}" ajax="false" 
actionListener="#{documentsBean.fileDownloadController(row)}">
<p:fileDownload value="#{documentsBean.fileStream}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Above is the command link triggering the file download and it is included inside a data-table, the data-table itself is inserted in a modal dialog. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask] and improve your question, see also point 1 in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO please include some of what you tried so far to help you improve it

Answer (score 0):

I Tested this method and it's worked fine for me, but to make a complete answer add some code to understand if there is a problem

```
public void downloaddoc(FileUploadEvent file) throws FileNotFoundException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
InputStream input = file.getFile().getInputstream();

ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getFile().getName(), file.getFile().getName()));
}
```

you can read more in [Primefaces Web Site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml)

Hope that helped you.